# Codec error after joomla upgrade to 3.1

Tags: joomla

I have a problem with my Site. I upgraded the System from 2.5 to 3.1 
The Upgrade  didn't make any Problems, but the Site has any mistakes. When i go to the Site it Looks perfect, but if i change to the contact information i get a white Site, which Shows only all email addresses from this article after loaded. I searched many hours to find the fault. Now i know the Problem 
It was the "@" Symbol. If any @ Symbol is in the Content, my Site doesn't work. But if i change all "@" to the html Codec "&#64" it works

Okay, i know the Problem but what can i do? There are a Lot of old article and i can't check all of them. It will be need too many hours to search for @ in every article. And Users create every time new articles, because there is a Blog

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with email cloaking that was changed in Joomla 3.0.

If you turn off the plugin called "Content - Email cloaking" it should work. Let me know if it does.